# Hilbert scheme of relative subschemes of lenght 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hilbert-schemes

Let $\mathfrak X \rightarrow S$ a smooth projective family over the spectrum of a dvr. We know that $(\mathfrak X _{\eta_R})^{[2]}$ and $(\mathfrak X _{p})^{[2]}$ are smooth, where $p$ is the closed point of $S$ and $^{[2]}$ stands for Hilbert scheme of two points (or subschemes of lenght $2$). Do we always have for the "global" Hilbert scheme, $\mathfrak X ^{[2]} \rightarrow S$ smooth ?

Comment: Yes, you do have that.  The standard obstruction theory for Hilbert schemes (as described in Artin's "Algebraization ... I" or in Chapter 1 of Koll'ar's "Rational curves ...") is actually an obstruction theory relative to a base $S$, at least as long as $\mathfrak{X}$ is flat over $S$ (otherwise there are some corrections).  So the usual argument -- length $2$ schemes are LCI and the global obstruction is an $H^1$ that vanishes on zero dimensional schemes -- proves smoothness over $S$ of the relative Hilbert scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not know length 2 subscheme were local complete intersection. Although in Kollar's book there is only the criterion for flatness (theorem I.2.15), it should indeed be easy to conclude from it.